# How to divide one existing model on django in two or more

Tags: python, sql, django, models

first of all sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem, i get a django app to make some changes and one of the things i have to do is divide the models. Because some of the models in the app are tooooo big. But i can't loose the database and the info on it because some of the models have more than 2000 objects.

I think i'm going to need to do some querys in SQL but maybe someone can give me a hand or ideas about how to do it.

This is the example of what i need

Example of the Original Model

```
class order(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
        brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        dispositive = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        serial = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        work = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        detail = models.TextField()
        price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        deposit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
```

Well i need to split that model on this

```
class Order(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateTimeField(
                blank=True, null=True)


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
        work = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        detail = models.TextField()
        price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        deposit = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class OrderDispositive(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
        brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        dispositive = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        serial = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Well i really have no idea about how to make this without loose any of the existing data in the database!

I know i have to modify after do this the views and the templates to get the correct data but i really need to fix some models to future modifications

Thanks for your Help!!!

Comment: Why do you need to split the model in the first place? In your new system will it be allowed to have more than one OrderDetail record for each order?

Comment: the model presented in the question is a example. One friend want's to implement part of the app that's have the big models, but in the new app that we are making we have different db structure but we can unify the structures if we could make this!

Comment: how can anyone give you a good answer if you don't provide accurate information?

Comment: Sorry about that, maybe because of my bad English I can't do myself understand correctly. But i think that my question is clear, i only ask if anyone knows some way to split models in two or more models. Can't understand why you need to know why I need to accomplish this to give me an answer! @Ravi Kumar give me a good answer without ask me about my reason to do this!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by writing your [own migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

step1: Create new models without deleting original models.

step2: Then run makemigrations.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

before migrating modify your migration file to copy data to other tables.

**your_new_migrations.py**

```
def update_Orderdata(apps, schema_editor):
    old_order = apps.get_model("some_app", "order")

    for instance in old_order.objects.all():
        # copy data to new order

def update_OrderDetail(apps, schema_editor):
    # copy data new tables OrderDetail

def update_OrderDispositive(apps, schema_editor):
    # copy data to new table OrderDispositive

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # ... your existing dependencies
    ]

    operations = [


        # original migration, such:
        # new Order table table,
        # new OrderDetail table
        # new OrderDispositive table

        # add this operation  at last...

        migrations.RunPython(update_Orderdata, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
        migrations.RunPython(update_OrderDetail, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
        migrations.RunPython(update_OrderDispositive, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),

    ]
```

Then

```
python manage.py migrate app_name
```

step 3: Now remove original models(class order). and run makemigration & migrate

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migreate app_name
```

Note: Before trying above solution take backup of your database.